# How to fix lib libstdc++'s `std::variant` (from GCC 9.1) not working with Clang 8?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, libstdc++

MSYS2's GCC package was recently updated to 9.1, but Clang doesn't like the new `<variant>` libstdc++ header that comes with it.

When compiling following simple program:

```cpp
#include <variant>

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, float> x;
}
```

I get:

```
# clang++ -std=c++17 foo.cpp

In file included from foo.cpp:1:
Z:\...\msys2\mingw64\include\c++\9.1.0\variant:1559:55: error: '__get' is missing exception specification 'noexcept'
        friend constexpr decltype(auto) __detail::__variant::__get(_Vp&& __v);
                                                             ^
foo.cpp:5:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::variant<int, float>' requested here
    std::variant<int, float> x;
                             ^
Z:\...\msys2\mingw64\include\c++\9.1.0\variant:263:5: note: previous declaration is here
    __get(_Variant&& __v) noexcept
    ^
1 error generated.
```

[Here is the complete `<variant>` header if you want to look at it.](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1f54d412a517f3a4b82f3dd77517842fb4de099a/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/variant#L1559)

While I'm waiting for an official fix, I did as Clang suggested and added `noexcept` to the header.

It *seems* to work so far.

**Can this solution cause any problems? Should I do something else?**

Bonus points if you know if it's a libstdc++ bug or a Clang bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is correct. It's a libstdc++ bug, see https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41863 and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90397